# How do I calculate the first value in each group from every other value in the group to calculate change over time?

Tags: python, r, pandas, dplyr

In R I can calculate the change over time for each group in a data set like this:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(z) %>%
  mutate(diff = y - y[x == 0])
```

What is the equivalent in pandas?

I know that using pandas you can minus the first value of a column like this:

```
df['diff'] = df.y-df.y.iloc[0]
```

But how do you group by variable z?

Example data:

```
x   y   z
0   2   A
5   4   A
10  6   A
0   1   B
5   3   B
10  9   B
```

Expected output:

```
x   y   z   diff
0   2   A   0
5   4   A   2
10  6   A   4
0   1   B   0
5   5   B   4
10  9   B   8
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected output?

Comment: `df['diff'] = df['y'].sub(df.groupby('z')['y'].transform('first'))` or `df.groupby('z')['y'].diff()`?

Comment: @ansev Thanks for your quick one line answers, just the sort of thing I was looking for!

Comment: So why have you accepeted? The Answer? I could post the commet like a Answer and you could Accept It if you want :)

Comment: Sorry, both answers worked fine but yours was a bit more concise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```py
temp = df.groupby('z').\
    apply(lambda g: g.y - g.y[0]).\
    reset_index().\
    rename(columns={'y': 'diff'}).\
    drop('z', axis=1)

df.merge(temp, how='inner', left_index=True, right_on='level_1').\
    drop('level_1', axis=1)
```

Return:

```py
x   y   z   diff
0   2   A   0
5   4   A   2
10  6   A   4
0   1   B   0
5   5   B   4
10  9   B   8
```